# Prototypal inheritance property shadowing

Tags: javascript

With Property Shadowing, I am a bit confused as to what it really is.  Does it just mean that if an internal property exists, the prototype won't be reflected?

```
let foo = function() {
    this.word = "HI!";
}

foo.prototype.word = function() {
     return "123456";
}

let test = new foo();

// does this return "HI!" rather than "123456" because `word` exists as an 
// internal property and that takes importance vs. the prototype?

test.word;  // "HI!";
```

Comment: @Taplar thanks for catching that, I corrected that !

Comment: You're right. Very simply put, the prototype chain is just objects linking to other objects. You can imagine having `parent = {foo: 1}; child = {bar: 2}` and if you call `child.foo` it will check that object's properties, if it doesn't find it, it will check `parent`. When you do `this.word = "HI!"` you're setting that property on the current instance which is `child` in the previous example. The `parent` is the `foo.prototype` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the last line is an indication for the value of test.word and not actually setting test.word to "HI".

Yes, you are absolutely right `this.word = "HI!"` defines the word property as an own property for the foo object while defining the word function on foo's prototype means that it is an inheritable property. Own properties have higher precedence than inherited properties.

You can check [https://dmitripavlutin.com/own-and-inherited-properties-in-javascript](https://dmitripavlutin.com/own-and-inherited-properties-in-javascript/)